# PreferenceCategory title is wrong color on older devices

Tags: android, angular-material, android-preferences

I have the following AppTheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_purple_600</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_purple_800</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/md_pink_A200</item>

    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

However when I launch a preference screen on older devices the PreferenceCategory title color seems to be defaulting to the default teal accent color.  Is this a known bug, ie just another thing PreferenceThemeOverlayhas not covered.  Or possibly something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to the bug reported here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233934

It seems like they are already working to fix it.